# How to display error when searching MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

New to PHP and MySQL, have heard amazing things about this website from Leo Laporte and others. I am using a extremely basic PHP script to search a MySQL database of peoples names. I was wondering how I can have the search supply an error if there no one by that name in the database.

```
</p><?php

mysql_connect ("mysql.mydomain.us", "pnq_1","passwordremoved")  or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("pnq_soldiers");

$term = $_POST['term'];

$sql = mysql_query("select * from test_database where LN like '%$term%'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo 'Last Name: '.$row['LN'];
    echo '<br/> First Name: '.$row['FN'];
    echo '<br/> Middle Initial: '.$row['MI'];
    echo '<br/> Rank: '.$row['RNK'];
    echo '<br/> Company: '.$row['CO'];
    echo '<br/> Platoon: '.$row['PL'];
    echo '<br/> Roster Number: '.$row['RN'];
    echo '<br/><br/>';
    }


?>
```

Comment: For reference, `mysql_query` has been obsolete for years now.  Check out PDO and/or mysqli.

Comment: Consider using [PDO](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Oh, and you're leaving yourself vulnerable to SQL injection.  If you insist on using mysql functions and/or building SQL by hand, learn to love `mysql_real_escape_string` -- you'll be using it a *lot*.  Ideally, though, you'll upgrade and learn to love prepared statements even more.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping it simple... use `mysql_num_rows()`

```
</p><?php

mysql_connect ("mysql.mydomain.us", "pnq_1","passwordremoved")  or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("pnq_soldiers");

$term = $_POST['term'];

$sql = mysql_query("select * from test_database where LN like '%$term%'");

if(mysql_num_rows($sql) < 1) {

    echo 'Couldn\'t find anything for '.$term.'.';
}
else {

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo 'Last Name: '.$row['LN'];
    echo '<br/> First Name: '.$row['FN'];
    echo '<br/> Middle Initial: '.$row['MI'];
    echo '<br/> Rank: '.$row['RNK'];
    echo '<br/> Company: '.$row['CO'];
    echo '<br/> Platoon: '.$row['PL'];
    echo '<br/> Roster Number: '.$row['RN'];
    echo '<br/><br/>';
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: Worked flawlessly. Thanks much!

Answer (score 2):

Check to see how many rows were returned. If no rows were returned, you can display an error.

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from test_database where LN like '%$term%'");
if (mysql_num_rows($sql)) {
    // continue as normal
} else {
    echo "Error!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (mysql_num_rows($sql)==0){
    //error
}else{
    //process data, while loop
}
```

and of course don't use `mysql_` functions :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql_num_rows to test the number of rows in the result. 0 for no results.